# onsen ui sliding menu - html <a> tag to weblink - android back button press don't go back

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

I have tested without using onsen ui sliding menu template, with a simple html page. it is OK, I touch the link and browse and can go back by pressing android back button. 
But, in sliding menu template, I create  link, press and go into the weblinks and cannot back and exit the app.
Please help me solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: How can you test the Onsen UI sliding menu without using Onsen UI? Please provide some code

Comment: I create a phonegap project using "phonegap create test" and add a html file to www folder and run. It is OK. Here is the code that include in index.html just one file including link to external site .<html>
<head>
  </head>
  <body alink="#006600" link="orange" vlink="red">
  <div style="background-color:orange;text-align:center;">
  <a href="javascript:openlink('https://tlk.io/linktochat');" target="_blank" rel="external">Enter Chat Room</a>
  <script>
  function openlink(url) {
 window.open(url,"_blank","location=yes");  
  }
  </script>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you should try to use this plugin.

[InAppbrower](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)

Here is an example..

HTML

```
<a href="" onclick="popupInAppBrowser('https://www.google.com')">GOOGLE</a>
```

JS

```
function popupInAppBrowser(url) {

   var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'closebuttoncaption=Close,location=yes,transitionstyle=coverhorizontal,toolbarposition=top,clearcache=no,clearsessioncache=no');

   ref.addEventListener("exit", function () {
     ref.close();
   });

   ref.show();
}
```

Comment: I think InAppbrowser does not work although I install in project folder via phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser ... versions are phonegap 5.1.1 and inappbrowser 0.6.0

Comment: Thank you brother, I have tried your code. it is open in new screen but cannot go back and stuck in that page. I press back button and app cannot get back to the previous screen.